# Get base64 from image upload with file reader onloaded

Tags: javascript

I have this JS code. It reads the file upload and the goal is, if there was an upload, to rewrite the variable src with the base64 for the image.

```
var file = document.getElementById('fileUpload').files[0];

var src = 'NOIMAGE';

if (file)
{
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onloadend = function () 
    {
        src = reader.result;
        console.log(src);
        
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}

console.log(src);
```

When it runs with a valid image upload, the first log prints the correct base64 string, but the second one still returns NOIMAGE. I think this is just a matter of changing a variable from within the onloadend. Thanks so much!

Comment: This will be helpful: https://www.programiz.com/javascript/variable-scope